# jQuery Validate rules wont apply

Tags: jquery-validate, asp.net-controls

I am trying to use jQuery validate for a form.

I have added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

My form:

```
<form id="Main">
  <asp:TextBox ID="Box" name="box" required runat="server"
</form>
```

At bottom of page

```
$('#Main').validate();
```

This works. Which is great. But if I remove the required attr and try say

```
$('#Main').validate({rules:{box:{required:true}}});
```

This does not work. For the life of me i cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

In the end I need that input to be required and numeric.

I tried adding 'number' as an attribute but that didn't work either.

some guidance would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: In the future, when asking about client-side code, please show the client-side code _as seen by the browser_.  `<asp: `, etc., is not what renders in the browser. You might have seen your actual mistake sooner, or we would have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of validation plugins available, after some searching I think I found the plugin you're using based on the usage [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

I created a fiddle to demo how to make a field required and numeric ... [click here for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38abK/).

Based on the code you provided, it looks like you're only including the base `validate.js` library.  You need to be sure to include the `css` file, and if you want to use some out of the box validations, such as number validations then you will also need to include the `additional-methods.js` file.  All these files can be found [HERE](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/).

Here is the code from the fiddle above..

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" class="box" id="box" name="box">
    <br/>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#myform" ).validate(
     {
      rules: 
      {
        box: 
        {
          required: true,
          number: true
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem was two fold. First: the Nuget package for this plugin does not install all the proper files, I did not have the additional-methods.js, Second: I mistakenly had my form within another form which was causing problems.